# Semantic web : Degree of relationship between 2 entities in a single ontology

Tags: semantic-web

Suppose that we have concepts in an ontology like: grand_mother, mother, and son.
grand_mother concept  has some entities like: Mrs. Brown, Mrs. Linda...
mother concept  has some entities like: Mrs. Jennifer, Mrs. King..
son concept has: Mike, Bill..

The degree of entities belong to 2 neighbor concepts (like mother and son, or grand_mother and mother) is 0.6. the degree of entities belongs to 2 far concepts (like son and grand_mother) is : 0.6 * 0.6.

User can type some keywords to the search box, and I must measure the degree of them.
For example, 1st keyword is Mrs. Brown and 2nd is Mike. 
I have no idea how to do it? (use reasoners but I don't know how to measure the degree of them). Have technologies to do it?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I think the keyword that you're looking for is weighted graphs, and a shortest path algorithm eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra's_algorithm